# What word describes the relationship between words like "art" and "artist?"

Tags: expressions

An example sentence:

> The word "art," and its ______ "artist," are used too liberally in our culture.

I suppose "derivative" would work there but I'm wondering if there's a more specific one.

Thanks!

Comment: The [morphology is  derivational](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf). So the technical term is _derived form_, since it's not an inflected form and not a root. _Derivation_ will work, but it's easier, terminologically speaking, to go from the actual word to its root or stem.

Comment: Ah, okay. So "artist" is a derivation of "art." Is "derivative" the wrong part of speech in this application?

Comment: No, it's fine, but then you get into semantic difficulties if you're not talking to linguists, because the popular meaning is pretty vacuous. BTW, the _-ist_ suffix is an agentive nominalizer.

Comment: I don't have the ability to upvote your comments so instead I'll just say "Thank you!" :)

Comment: Avoiding "derivative", you may say:  *The word "art", and the same family words such as "artist",  are used too liberally in our culture*.

Comment: So, you aren't looking for the specific term, 'agent-noun'? "agent word  n. Grammar a word that indicates agency or active force; esp. a word that denotes the doer of an action; = agent noun n."

Comment: @JEL I don't know. I'm not familiar with the term "agent-noun." But now that you've said it I can see that an artist is an agent of art. So that sounds like a pretty fitting word to describe their relationship.

Comment: Agent-noun does mean, precisely, words refering to the do-er of an action: an actor (agent-noun) acts, a scientist practices science, an artist makes art, and so on. You accepted the answer 'derivative', however, which is a *much* more general term. Hence my question to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you offered the term *derivative*, I assume that you are not looking for answers that mean "the person who produced the work of art." Instead I assume that you are looking for words the indicate the lexical relationship between them.

Certainly *derivative* could be the most correct choice. Try researching *lexical derivation* and you may find that you already have the best word.

You can also use words like *associated*, *related*, and so forth to indicate the relationship in a generic way. For example: "The word 'art,' and its related form 'artist,' are used too liberally in our culture."

The use of the word *form* to describe these types of related words appears to be quite frequent when discussing this topic.

Also investigate words such as *cognate* (typically used across languages).

Comment: Doesn't "and its related form, artist" sound a bit pompous? or fatuous? or both? Just saying. I mean, is "artist" really a form of art? Or something ...

Comment: Ah, so "artist" is a cognate of "art" then. I guess what I was really wondering is whether this relationship is one that has a specific grammatical term. It may be that it does not. I think if I went with simply "related" my meaning would be the clearest to most people. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb is, don't force it. If you can't think of a word, and a quick lookup in the thesaurus only muddles the matter further, rephrase (and simplify).

**The words art and artist are used too cavalierly in our culture.**

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I just thought there might be a word for this that I didn't know and then, having learned it, I wouldn't be "forcing it." If there isn't such a word then rephrasing in the manner you suggest would be a perfectly fine thing to do.